# React JS - render independent components

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am developing an application with Rails and React JS. My project is not "pure" single page (but I use Rails mainly as API). I decide to place two independent React components on different pages:

UPD:

(./application.js)

```js
........
ready(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<FirstComponent />, document.getElementById('first'));
  ReactDOM.render(<AnotherComponent />, document.getElementById('another'));
});
```

(./first_component_view.html.erb)

```html
........
<div id="first">
</div>
```

(./another_component_view.html.erb)

```html
........
<div id="another">
</div>
```

`FirstComponent` and `AnotherComponent` are all independent. Is it a bad practice - to render components as I demonstrated? Maybe there is an another (right) way to do that? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you presented the solution won't work as you expect.

If you really want to display more than one component then you can use a `<div>` or `React.Fragment` for wrapping different components. From the documentation for [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Please find the below example for `render`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Which is in your case might be the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
    <FirstComponent />
    <AnotherComponent />
</React.Fragment>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or with the shorter version what I really like using `<>components</>`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<>
    <FirstComponent />
    <AnotherComponent />
</>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Update:**

So it turned out from the comment section that OP's question is about how to represent different views based on a navigation component.

In my opinion if you want to render different component based on the selected navigation item, in the same time then it should be reflected on the URL part as well. Based on that you can use a `<Router>` high-order component for example.

So you can create `<Link>` components for your navigation items. Then for each you can create a `<Route>` inside a `<Router>` component.

Representing an example for your scenario:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/first">
      <FirstComponent />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/another">
      <AnotherComponent />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Suggested good training material to build your site with that is the following:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

I hope that helps!

Comment: Firstly thanks for response. (Sorry, I inaccurately presented the situation - see updates) My problem a few deep - I use Rails routes and different Rails views (pages). I want to render components on certain views only.

Comment: Do you think maybe if you have two separate components which should not communicate with each other - if that's the case - then those could be handled as different apps? What do you think?

Comment: I'm trying to present in more detail: first React component is navigation bar (it is should be on all pages). Second component is container with tiles - it should be on Home page only. Rest of components are "universal" - there are children components and may be placed into parents. Maybe the right way is to hide unnecessary components on certain pages?

Comment: Oh I see now. The correct way to handle different navigation items is to using `<Router>` for example. With that you can present different components based on the URL, e.g: appurl.com/first => rendering first component, appurl.com/another => rendering another component. I guess that's the thing what you are looking for. Read further here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: If I understand correctly, then I should to remove the Rails routing and to use the React routing, right?

Comment: Usually I use front-end routing instead of back-end routing in SPA scenarios. For these type of component rendering, if you want to represent different components from different navigation clicks then I would use React Router. Just updated my answer, please find an example there.